# Android studio auto backup source code in zip format in each day

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Is there any way to auto backup my source code in zip format in android studio?

Comment: Why would you do that? Isn't it better to use Git?

Comment: but how can i trust git ?

Comment: Git stores "snapshots" of your code whenever you commit. It saves these snapshots so you can revert back to them if you mess up something.

Comment: maybe they sell all private successful app code